# Protractor waits during ignore synchronization, browser implicitTimeout vs browser.wait timeout

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

I have an application that kicks off a $timeout when a button is clicked, so I must work with ignoreSynchronization set to true. During this time, I need to wait for elements to be added to the page, and I am experiencing some interesting behavior during the waits:

The wait timeout passed in during browser.wait(element, timeout, error message) does nothing. The only wait that matters is the implicitTimeout set on the browser. On top of that, the ENTIRE implicit timeout will be used. If the element is found to be present, it will continue checking until the end of the timeout. This means the tests will always run slowly, with the max time given.

```
describe('Cool Page', () =>{
  beforeEach(function(){
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    return browser.sleep(250);
  });

  afterEach(function(){
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    return browser.sleep(250);
  });

  it('can open menu with timeout', function(){
    // No timeout at this point
    coolPage.wait.ellipsesIcons().then(() =>{
       // Clicking the ellipses icons kicks off a $timeout of 100 seconds
       coolPage.ellipsesIcons.click().then(() =>{
          coolPage.wait.dropdownOptions().then(() => {
             expect(coolPage.dropdownOptions.getText()).toContain('Option 1');
          });
       });
    });
  });
})
```

.

```
  export = new CoolPage;
  class CoolPageextends PageObject {
    private elements;

    constructor(){
        super();
        ... // Lots of other stuff
        this.initWait();
    }

    ... // Initializing elements and other things

    private initWait() {
      this.wait = {
        ellipsesIcons: () => {
          // Timeout of 5 seconds will be used - regardless of isPresent resolving as true or false, the entire 5 seconds will be used
          browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);
          // The 2 milliseconds passed in here does nothing at all
          browser.wait(element(by.css('.fa-ellipses-h')).isPresent(), 2, 'Ellipses Icon(...) was not present in time');
          // Must reset implicit wait back to the original 25 seconds it was set too in the conf
          browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25000);
          return browser.sleep(150);
        },
        dropdownOptions: () => {
          // This two seconds wait WILL be used
          browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000);
          // This five second wait WILL NOT be used
          browser.wait(element(by.css('[name="change-status"]')).isPresent(), 5000, 'Options actions menu item was not present in time');
          browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25000);
          return browser.sleep(150);
        },
      }
    }
```

The timeouts passed in through browser.wait have no effect here. My questions are:

- What does the browser.wait timeout do?
- When is the implicit wait used? I thought it was only waiting for pages to load
- Is there any way to pass in a timeout that will actually be used?
- If not, is there any way for the wait to exit as soon as the condition is met, rather than using the entire timeout?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [expected conditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions) with browser wait. Take a look at [`it('should wait for a series of periodic increments'`](https://github.com/cnishina/protractor/blob/master/spec/ng2/async_spec.js) for an example using function `textToBePresentInElement`. To check if an element is present, I might try out `visibilityOf` or `presenceOf`.